# "GET" value without initialaztion in PHP

Tags: php

I'm upgrading an old system written in PHP. I encountered with a weird thing. The form parameters are being transferred in the "GET" method and instead of initializing a parameter like this:

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
```

there is a line for each parameter which looks like this:

```
if (empty($id)) $id = "";
```

when I add an echo of the value before

```
echo $id;
if ....
```

I'm getting the `$_GET["id"]` value. Obviously it works, but is this legal? using the GET parameter like a local variable without defining it explicitly?

Comment: Eeeeek, you're probably seeing a dependency on [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) Refactor, replace, burn, destory, nuke from orbit.

Comment: Is (the deprecated and scary) [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) turned on, perchance? If so, it's probably a very good job that you're upgrading the old system. Turn that the heck off as part of the upgrade :)

Comment: The right way is something along the lines of `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

> Note: Dealing with register_globals If the deprecated register_globals
>   directive is set to on then the variables within will also be made
>   available in the global scope of the script. For example,
>   $_POST['foo'] would also exist as $foo.

Note the *deprecated*.. Please do remove this from your code. Very bad bad design :)